# Retrieving font style, size and other attributes from a word document

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, docx, python-docx

I am working with python 3.6, my question is that is it possible to retrieve information from an existing document such as the font name of the text, the font  size,etc.

I have tried using python-docx to help me with it but when I try using run.font I only get None returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is helpful.

```
import docx
path = '/home/karamveer/Downloads/222.docx' #your docx file path
doc = docx.Document(path)
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    name = p.style.font.name
    size = p.style.font.size
    print name, size
```

Comment: This is returning None for me

Comment: `pip install python-docx` for Python 3.x and `pip install docx` for 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Using `run.font` work. The other answer didn't work as well for me so I'll answer this here

For font names, it will always return `None` if it's is "inherited from the style hierarchy," according to the documentation. I'll assume this means the default font of the document's default style. I've tried this with different fonts and it worked for me, giving me `None` for the default font and naming the different font names.

Font size appears to be the same, giving `None` for default sizes.

[Font documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#font-objects)

I used this to check and it worked for me. Hope it helps.

```py
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    fonts = []
    texts = []
    sizes = []
    for i in p.runs:
        fonts.append(i.font.name)
        texts.append(i.text)
        sizes.append(i.font.size)
        
    print(texts, fonts, sizes, sep="\n")
```